# Time for a Parachute to Reach Terminal Velocity?

Tags: kinematics, rocket-science

I've been trying to derive a formula for the time it takes a scale parachute (for model rockets) to reach its terminal velocity, but it has largely been to no avail.

I have $v_T = \sqrt{\frac{2mg}{\rho \cdot C_D \cdot A}}$, but I am unsure of where to proceed from there as it appears to be a matter of DEs.

Note that I am provided the values for the parachute's height, mass, and other parameters. I just need to derive a formula for the time it takes to reach $v_T$ under a gravitational force.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a DE problem, although the answer is obvious enough (infinite time required). Here's a quick sketch of how one might approach it.

$F = ma = dv/dt = mg - kv^2$ where $k$ is a constant (related to $\rho$, $A$ and $C_D$ in your expression for the terminal velocity. This is a separable differential equation, which you can solve to get an expression for $v$ as a function of $t$. There will be an arbitrary constant, which you can fix using your initial conditions ($v = 0$ at $t = 0$).

The expression for $v(t)$ will involve some exponential term, such that $v$ tends towards the terminal velocity, but never actually reaches it (similar to how $\exp[-x]$ tends towards $0$ for large $x$, but never actually reaches zero). This makes intuitive sense because the drag force will always increase, but never completely equal the weight.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#Velocity_of_a_falling_object) for more details.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thank you, thank you!

Comment: How is k related to \rho, C_D, and A  btw? TIA.

Comment: @EthanBarron https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#The_drag_equation